# Return 0 when some information DOESN'T EXIST (not when exists and return null)

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, chart.js

everyone. I have a *query* that returns a table containing values I need. That's good. But I also need, for each date already returned, that it returns also the velue 0 for `qtde_produzida` (that means “quantity produced”) in the days that there is nothing produced for that `op_filha`. For exemple: in this case below, the filters return to me two subproducts (each subproduct with one `op_filha`), and also return the quantity produced for each one (obviously, for the days that there was production), but I'd like to see the value 0 for those days that didn't have production. Is it possible?

My *query*:

```
DECLARE @dtInicial1 AS varchar(11), @dtFinal1 AS varchar(11), @opId1 AS INT, @setorId1 AS INT

SET @dtInicial1 = '2022-04-20'
SET @dtFinal1 = '2022-05-24'
SET @opId1 = 101855
SET @setorId1 = 6

SELECT
    DISTINCT MAX(CONVERT(varchar, C.con_dt_fim, 103)) AS data_final --final_date
    ,SUM(C.con_qtde_fim) AS qtde_produzida --qtty-produced
    ,R.rast AS op_filha --id for subproduct
    ,SP.Descricao AS descricao --subproduct's name
FROM
    Rastreio AS R
    INNER JOIN Contagem AS C ON C.rastreio_id = R.rast_id AND C.con_dt_exc IS NULL AND C.con_qtde_fim > 0
    INNER JOIN [DBG].[dbo].SubProduto AS SP ON OP.Cod_Produto = SP.CodigoSubProduto
WHERE
    R.op_id = @opId1
    AND OP.Cod_Setor = @setorId1
    AND FORMAT(C.con_dt_fim, 'MM-dd') BETWEEN FORMAT(CAST(@dtInicial1 AS DATE), 'MM-dd') AND FORMAT(CAST(@dtFinal1 AS DATE), 'MM-dd')
GROUP BY
    R.rast
    ,SP.Descricao
    ,R.rast_processo_sequencia
ORDER BY
    data_final
```

Printscreen of what is being returned:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLAZE.png)

It is for a *Chart.js*' graph. I imagine a *query* that would return something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghq7N.png)

Does someone know how to do that, please? Thank you all for reading.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify! [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to simplify.

Comment: A `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` is always a sign of a flaw in your query. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead.

Comment: Also `FORMAT` is a terribly inefficient function; its use it generally ill-advised. Using in a `WHERE` most certainly is a poor choice; use proper date boundaries.

Comment: Thank you Larnu for these advises, I'll remove `DISTINCT` and also learn how to use proper date instead of `FORMAT`. Please also help me about return 0 when there's is no values.

Comment: Presumably, you need to `LEFT JOIN` *from* (not to) a calendar table. If you don't have one, it's time to invest in one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an ISNULL. Try this:

```
SUM(ISNULL(C.con_qtde_fim,0)) AS qtde_produzida
```

or

```
ISNULL(SUM(C.con_qtde_fim),0) AS qtde_produzida
```

Comment: Thank you, Russell, for your help. But I've already tried using ISNULL. It doesn't work because there is no line where C.con_qtde_fim contains NULL, in fact it always contains a value > 0 or it just doesn't exist. Is there a way to add new lines automaticaly to show C.con_qtde_fim: 0 when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN: "LEFT JOIN Contagem..."